# Completeness property for subsets of R

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\mathbb {R}$ system has completeness property.

$\mathbb {N}$, $\mathbb {Z}$, $\mathbb {Q}$  are some subsets of real $\mathbb {R}$.

Why completeness property is not valid for its subusets (for example, completeness of $\mathbb {Q}$)?

(Also, about $\mathbb {Q}$ and discussing about its incompleteness, why should we look for $\sqrt {2}$ on the "ratinal line" while it is intrinsically an irrational number?)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is an intrinsically irrational number?

Comment: Simply consider the definition of completeness. Can you prove that the rationals has this property? Turns out, you cannot.

Comment: We look for this irrational number because we can find subsets of rational numbers that are bounded, but the upper bound is not rational, e.g. $\sqrt 2$. A simple example for the non-completeness of $\mathbb{Q}_{\geq 0}$: Take $\{-\frac 1 n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. The upper bound is $0$ but $0\notin\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Your post sounds like you are citing someone's opinions as undisputed facts. (Who is looking for $\sqrt{2}$ on the "rational line"?) Would you be able to give us a link to those sources that you are reading/listening to? It may be that they are presenting an incomplete (pun intended)/oversimplified/incorrect picture.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thx. I just mean that why we are using an irrational number like $\sqrt {n}$ in the context of $\mathbb {Q}$.

Comment: @LegNaiB ${0\in \mathbb {Q}}$. I got a little bit confused. Did you mean "..for the non-completeness of ${\mathbb {Q}\gt   0}$.."?

Comment: @StinkingBishop I started to read `Calculus: A Complete Course`, chapter Preliminaries, page 5. This question popped in my mind after a bit of reading. [link](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Calculus_a_Complete_Course/duZkvgAACAAJ?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your question only made sense in the *context* of that chapter. (Luckily there was a free preview on a book merchandise site, so I could see what it's all about.) That is why we on MSE insist on "context" - knowing what you've read we can tell better what issues you may have with that material - and help you better!

Comment: Sorry I meant for the non-completeness of $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$

Answer (score 2):

Your book defines completeness property as follows: *every subset bounded from above has the **least** upper bound* (also called a *supremum*).

This property sounds contrived when you first see it, but it is a crucial property of real numbers, which helps us prove a bunch of theorems in mathematical analysis which are essential in calculus, and which would otherwise be false!

Why is $\mathbb Q$ not complete? Look at the following set of rational numbers: $\{q\in\mathbb Q\mid q^2<2\}$. Note I am not mentioning $\sqrt{2}$, the above set is defined purely using rational numbers.

Of course this set is also bounded from above. If, say, $q^2<2<4$ then $q<2$. Thus, $2$ is one possible upper bound of this set. Examples of other upper bounds are: $1.5, 1.42, 1.415$ etc. (All of those are rational.) However, there is *no least upper bound*: whatever upper bound you choose, you can pick a smaller one. Obviously, knowing something about real numbers, you know that all those upper bounds must be bigger than $\sqrt{2}$, and for every rational number bigger than $\sqrt{2}$ you can pick a smaller one.

Thus, $\mathbb Q$ is incomplete.

The “rational line” talk is another way of the authors to picture for you what completeness means. Of course, you won’t find $\sqrt{2}$ on the rational line. What you *will* find is the set of all rational numbers with squares *below* $2$ (and add to that all negative rational numbers too, to get an “interval”), and on the other side you will find the set of positive rational numbers with squares *above* $2$.

> For you, knowing about real numbers, I am talking about sets $(-\infty,\sqrt{2})\cap\mathbb Q$ and $(\sqrt{2},+\infty)\cap\mathbb Q$.

Those two sets cover the whole “rational line” but it does look like something is missing, that there is a “gap” between those sets. Namely, the first set is bounded from above by any element of the second set, but the latter has no minimum, and similarly, the second set is bounded from below by any element of the first set, which does not have a maximum. This represents what we usually call a [Dedekind cut](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut).

This cannot happen with real numbers. In every Dedekind cut of real numbers there *is* a real number in between, which is either the maximum of the “lower” set or the minimum of the “upper” set. And, in fact, you can almost see how completeness property implies that (I don’t want to delve into a formal proof here). In fact, the converse is also true: from the fact that real numbers satisfy the “Dedekind cut” property, i.e. every Dedekind cut has a real number “between” the sets, one can prove the completeness property.

Answer (score 0):

**The Integers & Naturals:**

For the cases of $\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z}$ just consider what it means to be "complete".

- A metric space $(S,d)$ is "complete" if every Cauchy sequence in the space converges in the space.
- A sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $(S,d)$ is Cauchy if $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for all $n,m \ge N$,
  $$
  d(x_n,x_m) < \varepsilon
  $$

The choice of metric $d$ in the cases discussed is the absolute value: $d(x,y) := |x-y|$.

For those two cases - $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ - these actually *are* complete. The only Cauchy sequences in these spaces are the constant sequences, trivially convergent in the corresponding spaces.

---

**The Rationals:**

However, for the case of the rationals, we have even more Cauchy sequences to consider. The issue is that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, unlike the other two. Or put differently, the rationals are heavily interwoven into the reals, so that given an arbitrary distance $\varepsilon$ you want between distinct $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$, you can find $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $|x-y| < \varepsilon$ with no issue. (This statement on density can be framed as every real number, rational or irrational, being able to be approximated arbitrarily well by a sequence of rational numbers.)

You can't say this about the integers; two distinct integers have a distance at least $1$ from each other.

To see this incompleteness explicitly, it is simple to look at the sequence

$$x_n := \frac{ \lfloor 10^n \sqrt 2 \rfloor }{10^n}$$

This essentially gives the decimal approximation of $\sqrt 2$:

$$1 \qquad 1.4 \qquad 1.41 \qquad 1.414 \qquad 1.4142 \qquad \cdots$$

This sequence clearly converges to $\sqrt 2$, and is made of only rational numbers. Since it converges, it is Cauchy. However, the limit $\sqrt 2 \not \in \mathbb{Q}$, so $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete.